# Pusher and Laravel 5.3 Event Broadcasting

Tags: laravel, events, websocket, pusher, broadcasting

Trying to use Laravel 5.3 with pusher, but it seems its not working correct in my code.

My .env is correct

```
PUSHER_APP_ID= myappid
PUSHER_KEY= mykey
PUSHER_SECRET= mysecret
```

This is my 'pusher' configurations in broadcasting.php

```
    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
          'cluster' => 'eu',
          'encrypted' => true,
        ],
    ],
```

I created an event, here it is

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class ProposalEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    /**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return ['test-channel'];
    // return new PrivateChannel('test-channel');
    // return new PresenceChannel('test-channel');
}
}
```

my javascript

```
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var pusher = new Pusher("mykey", {
  cluster: 'eu',
  encrypted: true
});
var channel = pusher.subscribe('test-channel');
channel.bind('App\\Events\\ProposalEvent', function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

and finally in my view

```
event(new App\Events\ProposalEvent('some data'));
```

unfortunately this is not working for me, but when i use pusher->trigger like this, without event, it working fine, and i see message in pusher debug console

```
$options = array(
  'cluster' => 'eu',
  'encrypted' => true
);
$pusher = new Pusher(
  'mykey',
  'mysecret',
  'myid',
  $options
);

$data['message'] = 'some data';
$pusher->trigger('test-channel', 'my-event', $data);
```

I have searched for solution in Laravel documentation and other resources. There are questions with same problem in stackoverflow, but there are no response.I will be grateful if somebody can help me, because i can't find solution for several days

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in the same situation and found out that I wasn't using the queue!

In the documentation it says

> Before broadcasting events, you will also need to configure and run a queue listener. All event broadcasting is done via queued jobs so that the response time of your application is not seriously affected.

I deleted the config/queue.php file before since I thought I wasn't using it. Maybe you're doing the same thing as me or having some problem with the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass pusher credentials directly through config/broadcasting.php

It worked for me.

```
'default' =>  'pusher',
'connections' => [

    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => '***',
        'secret' => '**',
        'app_id' => '**',
        'options' => [
        ],
    ],
],
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

triggering event in the views is a mistake when a page is loaded the php is execute first then js is loaded wich mean that you fired event with php before js listner wich will displaye an error  this can the first case 
the second case is that you didn't downloaded https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
if you did go to php.ini and in [curl]you will find somthing like curl-info unecomment it 
and right the path to culr file